# Get column names stored in a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has just a code for the individual column name like "A1G", "Z8H" etc.
[image]

This table is a really huge table. Therefore it would not help to manually add the alias name in the SELECT Statement like.

The description for each column code is stored in a different table:
[image]

Now I would like to SELECT * from the first table but with the right column header name.
This is stored in the second table within the filters Schema = 'ABC' and Table = 'A'.
That would be desired output:

[image]

How would you do that in SQL?
How can I change the column name?

Comment: [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73) ?

Comment: That's pretty bad sample data. Where does "Size" (in desired output) come from? Two "Text" values make confusion. What is Z8H's purpose? You could have posted more descriptive example which would make it clearer (as you're dealing with a huge table anyway; 3-4 sample rows would be enough, but - posting just one which doesn't help much (to me, at least) ...

Comment: @Littlefoot: Thanks for your feedback. I just shared better examples - hoppefully.

Comment: Your data model is inappropriate. Dont mix structure and data. Either A1G is part of the structure as a column name, but then it should be part of the structure, i.e. a column name, throuout your database. Or A1G is just data, but then it must not be a column name. (To me it looks like data. So you should alter the first table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off just creating a view with all the columns aliased to your preferred names. Once that's done you can select from the view and get the data back with the headings you want.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Inner Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_inner_join.asp)
Or [Left Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

Comment: Ok, but how to a get the column name in the SELECT statement?

Comment: `TableNameOrAlias.ColumnName`

Or are you trying to get the data from the table to be the column header? Perhaps you could rephrase your question and provide an example of the current data and the desired output format?